# how can I use both required_if and required_without for validation in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I want to make validation this: `body.*.image.file` is **required** when value of `body.*.type` is **left** or **right** and `body.*.image.saved` is **empty**.

I tried this:

```php
$validator = Validator::make($input, [
    'body' => 'required|array',
    'body.*.type' => 'required|in:left,right,center',
    'body.*.image.saved' => 'nullable|json',
    'body.*.image.file' => 'required_if:body.*.type,left,right|required_without:body.*.image.saved',
]);
```

but it returns wrong result.

Comment: Please edit your question to include output from `dd($input)`

Comment: As well as what exactly "wrong result" means. What error message do you get?

Answer (score 0):

```
'body.*.image.file' =>  Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
                return ($request->input('body.*.type') == left || $request->input('body.*.type') == right) && empty($request->body.*.image.saved);
            }),
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.